# Javascript Canvas Lat Lng Plotting

Tags: javascript, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I want to create a data visualization similar to this:

[image]

...but for the entire globe. The canvas size will be arbitrary but won't need to resize with the browser (I will set the width and height before I start plotting points). I need to figure out a way of converting latitude and longitude coordinates to points on the canvas. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to choose projection. Then you can use proper formula. Or you can just use existent solution like [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) for example. This is JS port of well-known proj utility for working with various projections.

I would recommend to use Miller Projection for the visualizations on the whole globe. You can find formulas [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillerCylindricalProjection.html).

Comment: You could render the lat/lon points on a sphere rendered in the canvas viewport with no projection needed.

Comment: Don't understand you. What do you mean by "no projection needed". Anyway you need some formulas to convert points from polar coordinates in 3d to coordinates in cartesian 2d space.

Comment: If you render the points on a sphere, and then render that 3d sphere, you don't need a projection. If you are rendering lat/lon on a flat, 2d surface, then you need a projection.  Yes, you would need to convert lat/lon to Cartesian for canvas graphis rendering (see geodetic to ECEF). http://www.webglearth.org/